# How to traverse through JSON data structure in PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, dictionary, hashtable, powershell-5.0

I am new to PowerShell, learning it on the fly coming from Python background.

I am pulling data from another tool where the data is retrieved through a REST call.

METERS variable is stored in this format in the source.

```
{
    "500 HR": 500,
    "1000 HR": 1000,
    "2000 HR": 2000
}
```

PowerShell code

```
#REST call to source
$meter=@{}
Foreach ($item in $origresult.Items)  {
$result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -Headers $headers -Method GET -ContentType application/json -ErrorVariable RespErr)
$meter.Add($item.Name,$result.Value)
}
Write-Host ($meter | Out-String) -ForegroundColor Red
```

This is the Output

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
LastUploaded                   2020-12-29T06:38:02
IsEnabled                      1       
METERS                         {...
ORGID                          WHS
```

How do I retrieve METERS and traverse through the dictionary? I tried this so far. Python spoiled me with its simple data structures, PowerShell is not so straightforward unless there is a simpler way to do this.

```
$mymeters = $meter.METERS | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host ($mymeters | Out-String) -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Output

```
500 HR   : 500
1000 HR  : 1000
2000 HR  : 2000
```

Here are somethings I have tried so far -

```
$mymeters = [ordered]@{}
" Here is the item $mymeters.Get_Item(500 HR)" #my silly attempt!
# Looping is a no go either - it says specialized ordered dictionary
foreach ($ind in $mymeters) {
" --> $ind"
}
```

Output

```
 Here is the item System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.Get_Item(500 HR)
 --> System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary
```

I might be missing something real basic but I am unable to figure it out on my own! Any help is really appreciated. All I want is to traverse on the METERS hashtable/dictionary and call a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before getting into the meat of it, let's review a few PowerShell syntax basics and see if we can re-use some of your Pythonic intuition :)

### Member access

Just like in Python, you can reference the properties of an object by *name* using the `.` member access operator - for non-contiguous names, use quotes:

```
$mymeters = $meter.METERS | ConvertFrom-Json
$mymeters.'500 HR'  # evaluates to `500`
```

### String expressions

String literals in PowerShell comes in two distinct flavours:

- Single-quoted strings (`'Hello World!'`)

  - These are *verbatim* string literals, and the only supported escape sequence is `''` (literal single-quote)
- Double-quoted strings (`"Hello World!"`)

  - These are *expandable* string literals - automatic interpolation of `$variable` tokens and `$()` subexpressions will occur unless explicitly escaped - `` ` `` is the escape character, and common sequences you'd expect in most C-like languages (`` `n ``, `` `t ``, `` `r ``, etc.) are natively recognized.

Arbitrary expressions (like `$dictionary.get_Item('some key')`) will *not* be evaluated as-is, however.

To get around that, we can either use the `-f` string format operator:

```
$mymeters = [ordered]@{}
"Here is item '500 HR': {0}" -f $mymeters['500 HR']
```

`-f` should feel familiar if your used to Python3's `f` strings, but with a caveat - PowerShell's `-f` operator is a thin wrapper around [`String.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0), and `String.Format()` *only* supports 0-based placeholders - `'{0} {1}' -f 1,2` is valid but `'{} {}' -f 1,2` is not.

Another option is to wrap the expression in a `$()` sub-expression operator inside a double-quoted string literal:

```
$mymeters = [ordered]@{}
"Here is item '500 HR': $($mymeters['500 HR'])"
```

Take note that dictionaries in PowerShell supports keyed index access with `[]` - just like Python :)

---

Not unlike Python, PowerShell (and .NET in general) has powerful *introspection* capabilities as well.

Dynamically discovering and iterating the properties of any object is as simple as referencing a special member named `psobject`:

```
foreach($propertyMetadataEntry in $someObject.psobject.Properties){
    "Property: {0,-20} = {1}" -f $propertyMetadataEntry.Name,$propertyMetadataEntry.Value
}
```

Or in your case:

```
$mymeters = $meter.METERS | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach($meterReading in $mymeters.psobject.Properties){
    "Meter: {0,-20} = {1}" -f $meterReading.Name,$meterReading.Value

    # do whatever else you please with $meterReading here :)
}
```

This will work for any *scalar* object (like the object returned by `ConvertFrom-Json` or `Invoke-RestMethod`).

For iterating over the entries in a *dictionary*, you need to explicitly call `.GetEnumerator()`:

```
$dictionary = [ordered]@{ A = 1; B = 2; C =3 }
foreach($keyValuePair in $dictionary.GetEnumerator()){
    "Dictionary Entry: {0} = {1}" -f $keyValuePair.Key,$keyValuePair.Value
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the basics and the 101, really helped understand the nuances when compared to Python. I still got this when I tried your approach - Meter: Count                = 0
Meter: IsReadOnly           = False
Meter: Keys                 = System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection
Meter: Values               = System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary+OrderedDictionaryKeyValueCollection
Meter: IsFixedSize          = False
Meter: SyncRoot             = System.Object
Meter: IsSynchronized       = False

Comment: Those _are_ the properties of an ordered dictionary object (like the one produced by `[ordered]@{}`). If you want the _entries_ in a dictionary, you'll need to obtain an enumerator: `foreach($kvp in $dictionary.GetEnumerator()){ $kvp.Key,$kvp.Value -join '='}`

Comment: $mymeters = $meter.METERS | ConvertFrom-Json

           foreach($kvp in $mymeters.GetEnumerator())
           { 
               " --> I got here <-- "
               $kvp.Key,$kvp.Value -join '='
           } I got a null-valued expression error, You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: The other way around - `ConvertFrom-Json` returns a single `[PSCustomObject]`, against which you'll want to iterate over `.psobject.Properties`. `[ordered]@{}`, on the other hand, returns an ordered dictionary - and for _dictionaries_, you need `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: Ah, that did the trick, thank you so much! I used this foreach($meterReading in $mymeters.psobject.Properties) like you suggested.

Comment: You were on fire today! Great info.

Answer (score 1):

Please check my answer below:

1.) I tested the stuff on powershell 5.x. Newer or older Versions of powershell (particulary older) might work slightly different

2.) Invoke-Restmethod does automatically convert the json response into a powershell object, so no further processing needed. Get rid of all the assignment into an hashtable.

```
$responseJson = '{
    "500 HR": 500,
    "1000 HR": 1000,
    "2000 HR": 2000
}'

$response = $responseJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$nodes = (Get-Member -inputobject $response  -MemberType NoteProperty).Name

$nodes | ForEach-Object {
    echo ("Element: $_ Result: " +$response.$_)
    
}

echo "Another one"

#alternative
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    echo ("Element: $node Result: " +$response.$node)
}
```

3.) I think the response is bad formated, so if you have control over the restservice I recommend something like this:

```
$responseJson = '{
    "hr": [
     500,
    1000,
    2000
    ]
}'

$response = $responseJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$response.hr | ForEach-Object {
    echo ("Element: $_ Result: " +$response.$_)
    
}
```

Comment: I do have some control over the source, the way METERS has a JSON string can be changed. I need key,value pairs, some edge cases like 12KHR: 12000 and the like. I am able to traverse through the meters with your nodes logic. I got this as output for both options you provided  - Ex. Element: 500 HR Result: , can I get key,value output instead? $response.$node or $response.$_ is blank.

Comment: Hi, the Key is in $node and the value is in $response.node or what am I missing?

Comment: My apologies, variable mess  up on my part. This worked too. Thanks again!